# SQL Server large transaction, then occasional command timeouts

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I have a batch process that imports large amounts of data.  I am doing this by reading in a large text file and, parsing, then executing inserts, updates and deletes as dictated by the data.  These are simple statements being executed as Stored Procedures.  The batch of stored procedure calls are wrapped inside a transaction to be sure the file is completely processed before moving on.  The batch import is done once a week.  If a client gets behind, there could be several large transactions in a row.  When this happens, I occasionally get command timeouts in transactions after the first one.  I have increased the command timeout to 120 seconds.  Works fine so far, but, on a slow computer, it might not.  I have noticed that the timeout often occurs on an:

```
Update <table> set <columns> where <pk = some value>
```

I thought that perhaps SQL is still updating indexes in the background.  Any ideas on what is going on?

I realize that I could use something like SqlBulkCopy, but, that is not an option right now.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: You probably have a lock somewhere. Is this is your main production transactional DB, as in other people are querying it as you are updating it? If so, your transaction could be locking it up.

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is effectively a single user database.  My testing, where I am getting the timeout is a dev machine with no other users.  Strangely, increasing the timeout made the problem go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your sproc go row-by-row or does it do set-based INSERTS, UPDATES and so forth?  The answer to this question will become important a few paragraphs down.

But first, the problem with expanding the timeout is the n+1 problem, no matter how long you make it there will be that case that still goes over.  So expanding the timeout is not a permanent sleep-at-night-like-a-baby solution.  Much better is to eliminate the need for the timeout by breaking up the job.

First thing you do is eliminate that wrapping transaction.  The resources required to maintain locks explode as the row count in the operation goes up, so that batch operations like this often go faster if you break them up into smaller steps that require smaller transactions.

The next step, since you no longer have that wrapping transaction, is to make sure that each individual step can be safely re-run in the event of a failed job, no matter where the process was when it failed.  This is called "idempotent" if you want to be fancy, or "re-runnable" if you want to use plain English.

Now we return to the question, is your sproc going row-by-row or is it executing INSERTS that affect many rows, then UPDATES, and so on.

CASE ROW-BY-ROW:  Easiest, though probably the slowest.  Gobble the text file into an "INBOX" table and add a column "Processed" which is Y/N.  As you go row by row, you do your INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE, then update the row in the inbox table as Processed=Y.  If you pull the plug at any stage, the sproc simply resumes looking at unprocessed rows until there are none left.  This gives you the same affect as the great big wrapping transaction without the overhead.  You can run dozens of files in a row and the server will never time out.

CASE SET-BASED:  If you are doing set-based DML, then you modify the INSERT so it pulls from the INBOX table and INSERTS into the target table for all rows not already there.  This makes it re-runnable.   DELETE statements don't need this check, if you re-run a set-based DELETE and it has already run, it simply finds nothing to delete.  UPDATE is basically the same as DELETE in.

This is general advice based on what you stated about your issue.  To get more specific I would need to know more about the process.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the fragmentation of your indexes and rebuild them if necessary.

Also I would run your queries in SSMS and turn on include actual execution plan and see if you have any issues.

Comment: This will likely be my short term solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to investigate first what is causing the timeout. As with any SQL Server performance investigation, the best approach is the [Waits and Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) methodology. Basically you need to look at the `wait_type`, `wait_time` and `wait_resource` in [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx) for the session that is doing the `UPDATE`. This will show what is blocking/slowing the UPDATE, and according to this find you can do an appropriate action/solution. If I'd venture a shot in the dark, you are hitting [log auto-growth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191263.aspx) events in your testing. None the less, the proper solution is to measure first and cut second: investigate to identify the root cause of the timeout, and only then proceed with changes.